# How to write a C program to calculate factor

Tags: c

So the problem is to solve this:

> 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/ 3! +.... x^n/n!

And, this is what i have done so far.

```c
float sum(int x, int n)
{
    float sum = 1;
    int fact, temp;

    for (int i= 1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        
        fact =1;
        //Caculate N!
        for (int j=1; j<n; j++)
        {
            temp = j;
            fact = fact *temp;
        }
        
        //Caculate X^N/N!
        sum += pow(x,i)/fact ;
    }
    
return sum;
}
```

But when i try N = 4, X= 2 it should be 7, instead it was 9.

Comment: Your loop that is commented to compute N! actually calculates (n-1)!, but should calculate i!

Comment: It seems that using a debugger or changing it to print out values at each iteration would help you understand what your code is doing.

Comment: It is wasteful to compute the factorial anew at each loop iteration, and before you get to too many terms it will overrun the upper bound of type `int`.  Consider instead computing each term from the preceding one by multiplying by `x` and dividing by `i`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger can you show me what you mean? by divide by `i` because if i not wrong for example 5 the correct ans should be 5! ?

Comment: It should be `j<=i` , so `for (int j=1; j<=i; j++)`

Comment: You're computing n! but I think you should be computing i!

Comment: @sittsering if so it will be out of range ? since I is already go up?

Comment: @NguyenTanHiep, for example, consider the second term in the sum, x^2/2!.  If you multiply this by x/3 (being careful to use floating-point division), then the result is the third term in the sum, x^3/3!.  More generally, if T(i) is the *i*th term in the sum then it can be expressed as T(0) == 1, T(i > 0) = T(i-1)*x/i.  Not only will computing each term from the previous in that way be more efficient, but it will also avoid the factorial computation overflowing.

Comment: Can you explant it ? @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica

Comment: In your formula 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/ 3! +.... x^n/n! your divisors are 0!, 1!, 2!, 3!, etc. In your function, `n` is the maximum degree of the polynomial - but at each iteration, `i` is the degree of the polynomial at that iteration. Therefore, in `sum` you should be dividing by `i!`, not `n!`.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica Oh, so that what im stuck at xD thankss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
float sum(int x, int n)
{
    float sum = 1;
    int fact = 1, temp;

    for (int i= 1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        fact*=i;
        
        //Caculate X^N/N!
        sum += pow(x,i)/fact ;
    }
    
return sum;
}

int main(){
    cout<<sum(2,4)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be finding factorial of `i`.

```
for (int j=2; j<=i; j++)
{
    fact = fact * j;
}
```

1 + x^1/1! + x^2/2! + x^3/ 3! +.... x^n/n!
So in 1st iteration -`i=1`, you are to find factorial of `1` that is `i`, not `n`.
Like wise in 2nd iteration - `i=2`, find factorial of `2` that is `i`.
lastly when `i=n`, factorial of `n` that is `i`.

Comment: It still not work. it should be output 7 but it output 10?

Comment: That mean it will only work will N under 3? since in the second loop it already finish the condition and move on?

Comment: No, there are 2 loop, in each iteration of outer loop, `i` value will change.

Comment: inner loop is for finding factorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily calculate power of x and factorial for each step incrementally.

```
float sum(int x, int n)
{
    float sum = 1;
    int powx = 1, fact = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        // incremental power and factorial 
        powx *= x;
        fact *= i;

        // sum it up
        sum += powx / fact;
    }
    
    return sum;
}
```